# Jquery - Does $(document).text() return all nodes text including nodes got from Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, text, document

I am trying to get the text of a web page that do an ajax call do get part of the content
It seem that $(document).text() don't return all the web page text.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you run `.text()` **after** any AJAX action, there should be no problems getting the current text of a webpage.